# How to remove the redirect from an ASP.NET Core webapi and return HTTP 401?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-core

Following the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983188/blocking-anonymous-access-by-default-in-asp-net-5/31983548#31983548), I have added authorization on everything by default, using the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection aServices)
{
  aServices.AddMvc(options =>
  {
     var lBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser();

     var lFilter = new AuthorizeFilter(lBuilder.Build());
     options.Filters.Add(lFilter);
   });

   aServices.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder aApp, IHostingEnvironment aEnv, ILoggerFactory aLoggerFactory)
{
  aApp.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
  });
}
```

However when someone tries to access something unauthorized, it returns a (what seems a default) redirect URL (http://foo.bar/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Ffoobar%2F).

I want it to return a HTTP 401 only, instead of a redirect.

How can I do this in ASP.NET 5 for a WebAPI?

Comment: Please include your code here rather than linking to the other question.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code.

Comment: Hi, is this all the code? What authentication do you use? Token, cookie, external?

Comment: Hello @Geerten, could you change the accepted answer since that method isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had with this problem in an Angular2 + ASP.NET Core application. I managed to fix it in the following way:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>   {
    // ...
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
    // ...
});
```

If this is not working for you, you can try with the following method instead:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>   {
    // ...
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
       OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
       {
           if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")) 
           {
               ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
               // added for .NET Core 1.0.1 and above (thanks to @Sean for the update)
               ctx.Response.WriteAsync("{\"error\": " + ctx.Response.StatusCode + "}");
           }
           else
           {
               ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
           }
           return Task.FromResult(0);
       }
    };
    // ...
}
```

**Update for Asp.Net Core 2.0**

Cookie options are now configured in the following way:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
            {
                config.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = ctx => {
                        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        }
                        else {
                            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: Question/clarification -- Why should we check for HTTP 200 before changing it? If the redirect is happening, shouldn't we just act regardless? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer, pointed me in the right direction. You might also want to use OnRedirectToAccessDenied for authenticated (logged in) but not authorized users with HttpStatusCode.Forbidden for the api case and a redirect without the ReturnString for View users.

Comment: This is the correct answer for ASP.NET MVC Core, and with Angular 2 apps. Thank you!!!! Drove me bunkers. Note: this is required when using JWT token auth via cookies - especially when switching from JWT bearer auth.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for .NET core 3.0 (preview) :/

Answer (score 5):

By the url you get redirected to I assume you're using cookie authentication.

You **should** get the desired results by setting the `LoginPath` property of the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to null or empty as [described](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/292#issuecomment-115573597) by one of the users.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "";
        });
```

It was probably working back then but it's **not working anymore** (because of [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blame/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L42) change).

I've submitted a [bug on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/505) for this.

I'll update the answer once it gets fixed.

Comment: Indeed I use cookie authentication, so I added the CookieAuthentication code. Thanks for added the bug request, it's not working over here as well!

Comment: Thanks for filing the issue. Reading the discussion was very helpful.

Comment: That github bug thread is a really good read I agree. Summary is really that using cookies isn't great for web apis.

Comment: No longer works. The `config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events` answer is the one that works now

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. 
I solved this adding by manually the services.

ConfigureServices method:

```
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore<User, IdentityRole, ApplicationDbContext>>();   
    services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserValidator<User>, UserValidator<User>>();
    services.AddTransient<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
    services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<User>, PasswordValidator<User>>();
    services.AddTransient<IdentityErrorDescriber, IdentityErrorDescriber>();
    services.AddTransient<ILogger<UserManager<User>>, Logger<UserManager<User>>>();
    services.AddTransient<UserManager<User>>();

    services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddAuthorization();


    services.AddCors(options=> {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders", (builder) => {
        builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate"); ;
    });
});


    services.AddAuthentication(options=> {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = "api1";
        options.ApiSecret = "secret";
    });
```

Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();

}
```

I am using aspnet core 2.0, IdentityServer 4 and aspnet identity.

Comment: Thank-you, your post helped me.

Comment: In my case the problem was I was using `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`. I thought It would just override all the parameters. Apparently I was wrong. You need to override `options.DefaultChallengeScheme` with `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` then It works.

Tested on *ASP.NET Core preview 3*

Answer (score 4):

Setting LoginPath = "" or null no longer works on Version 1.1.0.0. So here's what I did:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150),
            AuthenticationScheme = options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme,
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync,
                OnRedirectToLogin = async (context) => context.Response.StatusCode = 401,
                OnRedirectToAccessDenied = async (context) => context.Response.StatusCode = 403
            },
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
        });
```

Comment: Just a heads up - you should also have `await Task.FromResult(0);` so that any exceptions thrown in the async methods are observed. e.g. `OnRedirectToLogin = async (context) => { context.Response.StatusCode = 401; await Task.FromResult(0); },`

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, you should not use the `CookieAuthentication` only if you want to use your own Authentication Mechanism for example bypassing the `Identity` provider which not the case for most of us.

The default `Identity` provider use the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` behind the scene, you can configure it like the below.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
 {
     o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
     o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
     o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
     o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
     o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

     o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = null; // <-----
 })
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Tested in version `1.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

in case it helps, below is my answer - with dotnet 1.0.1

its based on Darkseal's answer except I had to add the line ctx.Response.WriteAsync() to stop the redirect to the default 401 URL (Account/Login)

```
        // Adds identity to the serviceCollection, so the applicationBuilder can UseIdentity
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {                
            //note: this has no effect - 401 still redirects to /Account/Login!
            //options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = null;

            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                {
                    //for WebApi: prevent aspnet core redirecting to 'Account/Login' on a 401:
                    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                    {
                        ctx.RedirectUri = null;
                        ctx.Response.WriteAsync("{\"error\": " + ctx.Response.StatusCode + "}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in `Startup` :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = (ctx) =>
                    {
                        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) =>
                    {
                        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```