# Asp.net Core action does not return 401 when using Authorize attribute on a thread without a principle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I wanted  to add a principle onto the thread by myself , *without* using the Identity mechanism which really reminds me the old membership/forms authentication mechanics.

So I've managed (successfully) to create a request with principle :

**MyAuthMiddleware.cs**

```
public class MyAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;


    public MyAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next )
    {
        _next = next;

    }


    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>  
        {  
            new Claim("userId", "22222222")  
        };  
        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims ,"MyAuthenticationType");  
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

         httpContext.User = principal;
         await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

**The Configure method:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //app.UseAuthentication(); //removed it. I will set the thread manually
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseMyAuthMiddleware(); // <---------- Myne

            app.UseMvc();
            app.Run(async context => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!"); });
        }
```

And here is the Action in the Controller: (Notice Authorize attribute)

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("data")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {

        var a=User.Claims.First(f => f.Type == "userId");
        return new JsonResult(new List<string> {"a", "b",a.ToString() , User.Identity.AuthenticationType});
    }
```

Ok Let's try calling this method, Please notice that this **does** work :

[image]

So where is the problem ?

Please notice that there is an `[Authorize]` attribute. Now let's remove
 setting principle on the thread ( by removing this line ) :

```
//httpContext.User = principal; // line is remarked
```

But now when I navigate to :

```
http://localhost:5330/api/cities/data
```

I'm being redirected to :

```
http://localhost:5330/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fcities%2Fdata
```

But I'm expecting to see Unauthorized error.

I'm after WebApi alike responses. This is not a website but an API.

**Question:**

Why don't I see the Unauthorized error ? And how can I make it appear?

Nb here is my ConfigureServices:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddAuthentication( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme ) 
                  .AddCookie( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,  a =>
                  {
                      a.LoginPath = "";
                      a.Cookie.Name = "myCookie";


                  });

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

**EDIT**

Currently What I've managed to do is to use OnRedirectionToLogin :

[image]

But it will be really disappointing if that's the way to go. I'm expecting it to be like webapi.

Comment: redirect page suggests you're using cookie authentication which has that behavior of redirecting to the login page (which will then set the cookie on login).  what do you have authentication wise in your `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: @deezg Thanks fore reply. Added to my question

Comment: yeah, right. this might be a good lead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878166/asp-net-core-2-0-disable-automatic-challenge

Comment: i am actually not sure what you're trying to accomplish. specifically, not sure why would you use cookie authentication but without signup page redirect. i usually use it together. and if i need webapi behavior then i don't use cookies at all but go with jwt or alike instead. So, i can't give you exact solution from the top of my head, but i'm sure its something around cookies. why? not sure.

Comment: Becuase it's a webapi. not a website. there is no where to be redirected. I'm expecting to see 401 when there's no principle on the thread.

Comment: but why authorization cookies then?

Comment: The cookie just hold info ( userId) which I'm putting on a thread. Let's go from the other side. I want to save in a cookie encrypted UserId which on each request i';m reading the userId and put a principle on a thread.BTW it's authentication not authorization

Comment: i know exactly what you're trying to do i just didn't do it that way for a long time and i'm not sure what's the proper way of doing it now. this might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863080/how-to-remove-the-redirect-from-an-asp-net-core-webapi-and-return-http-401  (sorry for not giving you definite answer)

Comment: When you say you *navigate* and it redirects, is this an XHR call you're making or are you just testing it in the browser?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Both in browser and fiddler I see the 302 : https://i.imgur.com/5WfQ9gt.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of the `OnRedirectToLogin` delegate looks like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs#L40):

```
public Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> OnRedirectToLogin { get; set; } = context =>
{
    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

As is clear from the code above, the response that gets sent to the client is dependent upon the result of `IsAjaxRequest(...)`, which itself looks like this:

```
private static bool IsAjaxRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    return string.Equals(request.Query["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
        string.Equals(request.Headers["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

This means that the response will be a `401` redirect if either a `X-Requested-With` request header or query-string value is set to `XMLHttpRequest`. When you hit your endpoint directly from the browser or from within e.g. Fiddler, this value is not set and so the response is a `302`, as observed. Otherwise, when using XHR or Fetch in the browser, this value gets set for you as a header and so a `401` is returned.

Comment: Confirming : adding this header (_which will be added by ajax by default imho_) - does return a 401 but still with a `Location` response header  ( which I have to sort out how to remove it) - https://i.imgur.com/FxBELor.jpg  .But strictly speaking , it does answer the core question