# .NET Core 3 (preview) Web API return UnAuthorized (401) instead of NotFound (404)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies

Having read through many posts, blogs and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863080/how-to-remove-the-redirect-from-an-asp-net-core-webapi-and-return-http-401), this code doesn't do what I expect it to do:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

An excerpt from an API controller (using the authorize attribute):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public class TravelPlanController : BaseController{
...
}
```

This is part of the startup configuration of a Web API in .NET Core 3.x (preview) and should return a **401 UnAuthorized** (which essentially should be UnAuthenticated) but instead returns a **404 NotFound**.

The 404 results from the fact that the default .NET Core Authentication Middleware redirects to something like */auth/login* and that route is not available (by design; it is an API not a MVC website). So the request *is* unauthorized, gets redirected by default, and results in a 404 :s

Both the apporaches of `OnRedirectToLogin` handlers should intercept this default behaviour, which is odd for a RESTfull API, and return a simple **401 UnAuthorized**. But they don't, breakpoint isn't hit in debug mode, Postman and an Angular app in Chrome both report a **404**.

Did anything change since .NET Core 3.x? Or did the solutions from others never really work.

Comment: How are you enforcing the authz here? e.g. using `[Authorize]`? Include the code if you can.

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes like this: `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]`

Comment: Do you have additional setup code for the authentication schemes, etc? I'd expect what you've shown to error out re a missing default authentication scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Working with **ASP.NET Core 3.x** (preview) and the default **Identity** provider the **order in which the above declarations are specified makes the difference** for the `OnRedirectToLogin` event to be fired.

I eloborated on this in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57308458/468910) as well.

Comment: Order has always been important.  That's not new in  V3

Comment: I thought only in the setup of the pipeline in the `Configure` method which makes sense. Not in the `ConfigureServices` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the *OnRedirectToAccessDenied* on the *Events* as you did for *OnRedirectToLogin*.

Comment: Hm, it was a solution for me in the AddCookie method.

Comment: I will give it another try in the upcoming days to check if I overlooked something. Thanks.