# How to prevent redirect to login url in case of unauthenticated API request?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1.8 Web Application uses ASP Identity.
All is working OK, when user try to navigate to a page which requires authentication, the response redirects the user to the login page.

Recently I created some API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult<string> PingAuth(string message)
    {
        return Ok($"Pong: {message}");
    }
```

During testing I noticed, that in case I call it with no authentication the response is the redirect, instead of the 401 Unauthorized.

**Question**

Is there any way to explain the api controller to send [401: Unauthorized] instead of [302: Found]?

Comment: You have configured only a single authorization policy (the default one), therefore all http requests will behave the same (i.e. will redirect)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863080/how-to-remove-the-redirect-from-an-asp-net-core-webapi-and-return-http-401

Comment: The question you referred is working with minor changes, I mean filtering which path `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie...`  should return with 302 and which with 401. However I still do not understand what to do with "policies" (your first comment)

Comment: Which kind of authentication are you using? Can you post the related configure code in the Startup.cs file? Here is a thread about [ASP.NET Core Web API unauthorized requests returns 302 redirect response instead of 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411296/asp-net-asp-net-core-web-api-unauthorized-requests-returns-302-redirect-respon), might be it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Authorize attribute's property Policy and require authenticated users:

In Startup, ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthorization(op=>{
            op.AddPolicy("AuthUsers", policy=>{
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            });
        });
```

Then you can use [Authorize(Policy="AuthUsers")]

Comment: Did exactly what you described, still I got the 302 Found and redirected to the login Url

Comment: Do you  "UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute"? This configuration can also cause bad 401 handling

Comment: No, I am not using UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute